# If .next() element is the .last() element?

Tags: jquery

I know it's quite simple, but `.next()` and `.last()` kind of confuse me. I'm kind of mixed up.

What I am essentially trying to do is add a class when the next element is the last of the kind in a list.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnwBC/3/)**

In my current code it adds the class after the last element is displayed, when it goes back to the first.

**jQuery:** *Im sure it has to do with the `.length`*

```
$("#next-button").on('click', function () {
    var nextItem  = $('.active').removeClass('active').next(),
        breadItem = $('.clickable').next();

    if (!nextItem.length) {
        nextItem = $('.item').first();

        //Here I try to add class ".last" to the last ".item" element
        $('.item').last().addClass('last');
    }
    nextItem.addClass('active');
    breadItem.addClass('clickable');  
});
```

This adds the class when you click on the last element going back towards the first.

Also for a bonus question, I am confused as to why when I add class `.clickable` to the breadcrumbs only the first one takes me to the right `data-id` check the **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnwBC/3/)**

I appreciate this community and all the help I am getting, for a expert in jQuery this will be quite easy, thanks for helping me learn.

Comment: Is it right that if the second last element becomes red, the last should become green?

Comment: can you clarify a bit more what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Well to be blunt, when "speed" is Red/active the next/last item which is flexibility should be green right after speed.. The last item in the list should get the class last when its active.

Comment: "Flexibility"/Last should get class `.last` when active... It gets class `.last` when the first item is active... so directly after speed the last item should be green.

Comment: Six upvotes for this question? Am I missing something?

Comment: I think it's because of the formating, which is quite ok. :)

Comment: Hey dont knock the upvotes :) that really is irrelevant though I just want to learn what I am doing wrong and find a solution.

Comment: your data-id isn't working is because the clickable class was added after initial load. Check out http://api.jquery.com/on/ you need something like $(".breadcrumb-trail").on("click", ".clickable .breadcrumb", function(event){}

Comment: ok sweet appreciate the resource, ill look it when I get the last item working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There u go for the first requirement

```
$("#next-button").on('click', function () {
    var nextItem  = $('.active').removeClass('active').next(),
        breadItem = $('.clickable').next();

    if (!nextItem.length) {
        nextItem = $('.item').first();
        $('.item').last().addClass('last');
    }
    nextItem.addClass('active');
    breadItem.addClass('clickable');
    // 1st Req 
    // Remove the last class for items
    $('.item').removeClass('last');
    var last = $('.item').last();
    // Check if the item is the last one
    // it true add last and remove active
    if(nextItem.is(last)) {
        nextItem.addClass('last').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

2nd requires event delegation since it's a dynamically added element

**UPDATE**

```
$(".breadcrumbs").on('click', '.clickable .breadcrumb', function () {
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    var theID = $(this).data("id");

    var selectedItem = $("#" + theID);
    selectedItem.addClass('active');

    $('.item').removeClass('last');
    var last = $('.item').last();
    if(selectedItem.is(last)) {
         selectedItem.addClass('last').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

### **[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/cnwBC/12/)**

Comment: This is nice, but I am not trying to add `.last` when its on "speed" but after active is removed from speed at the same time active is added to the last class, I want to add active to the last element. Does that make sense?... when the list comes to an end, the last element gets the class...

Comment: Ok awesome you all are the best, I am taking a look at @Marcel Gwerder code, then I am going to see this... I love having these options and seeing the different ways to write jQuery helps me learn.. I appreciate the effort! :)

Comment: Yes! Checked this fiddle and it looks great! you are the best @Sushanth -- Helped me twice in a row.. I hope to get good enough soon so I can start helping out like you guys

Comment: @Mike.. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: This is tough your code is fantastic but so is @koala_dev. I went with this code, because you removed the last class when the breadcrumb was clicked and it was not the last element.

Comment: Can you please help me with this: https://jsfiddle.net/egLefjwv/5/ I am having an issue with going to the first div if the last one is reached.

Answer (score 4):

You want to use jQuery `is()` to check if the next item is the last on any of your two lists

```
$("#next-button").on('click', function () {
    //enable next breadcrumb
    $('.clickable').next().addClass('clickable');
    var nextItem = $('.active').removeClass('active last').next();
    //start again
    if (!nextItem.length) {
        nextItem = $('.item:first,.breadcrumb-cell:first');
    }
    //mark as active
    nextItem.addClass('active');
    //check if is last
    if (nextItem.is('.breadcrumb-cell:last,.item:last')) 
        nextItem.addClass('last');
});
```

Also you need event delegation on the `breadcrumbs` parent for the click event since the `clickable` class will be added dynamically to your elements

```
$(".breadcrumbs").on('click','.clickable .breadcrumb',function () {
    //reset active and last
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    $('.last').removeClass('last');
    var theID = $(this).data("id");
    //get new item
    var selected = $("#" + theID);
    //mark item and breadcrumb as active
    $(this).parent().add(selected).addClass('active');
    //check if selected is last
    if(selected.is('.item:last'))
        //mark item and breadcrumb as last
        $(this).parent().add(selected).addClass('last'); 
});
```

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cnwBC/20/)**

Comment: So far this seems like the best solution, thanks for the effort to help out.

Comment: I'm just not sure if it makes sense to add a `last` class to the last item on a click event. The last item is always the same...
You can always check if the current active item is the last with the last-child selector. Or if last-child isn't the prefered option why not just add the last class from the beginning.

Comment: Yeah but with this bit of code `if(nextItem.is('.breadcrumb-cell:last,.item:last'))
       nextItem.addClass('last');` inside the 'if' I have flexibility to add classes and stuff to wherever I want. It's not about adding a class to the last item but doing stuff when it reaches the last item. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes for doing something else it makes sense.

Comment: yeah the only reason I was adding a class to the last item in the fiddle was for visual purposes so people would understand. Many times I am not specific about what I am doing in my live code, maybe that confuses some people, and I apologize for that.

Comment: You're great this helped me learn alot and I will revert to this post and use your code to learn from, but @Sushanth -- code removes the `.last` class when the breadcrumb item is clicked, making it more full.

Comment: @Mike I've updated with a more complete answer, Sushanth's answer still had some issues with the breadcrumbs being updated with the click event

Comment: Geeze this is good, I like this answer but I spent the last 30 min working with Sushanth's answer and already choose Sushanth's... Is there a way I can give you some more rep?

Comment: @Mike You could retract and mark this as your accepted answer but that's up to you. If you analyze both scrpts you'd find that they're practically the same (with my added functionality for the breadcrumbs) so I don't think you'd have a hard time adapting your code. Anyway, that's your choice and it'll be ok if you leave things as they are

Comment: Can you please help me with this: https://jsfiddle.net/egLefjwv/5/ I am having an issue with going to the first div if the last one is reached.

Answer (score 2):

How about just changing the css of the last active element ([**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cnwBC/4/)):

```
.item.active:last-child {
    color: green;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

And remove `$('.item').last().addClass('last');`.

Of course you can target the last item the exact same way in jQuery as in css:

```
$('.item.active:last-child')
```

**Edit**: If I get you right and you wan't to execute some code if you are on the last item then you are just missing one `next()`:

```
if(!nextItem.next().length) {
    console.log("Now on the last item");
}

if (!nextItem.length) {
    nextItem = $('.item').first();
}
```

Comment: Well, in my live code I need to do a lot of actions to the last `.item` so I need to be able to target the last item using jQuery.. Ill be adding classes to other elements if its on the last item.. It being green is just for testing purposes. Once I figure out how to manipulate the last item Ill have more flexibility

Comment: Im trying to think, if it will work I want to say if currentitem is last then add class to another element in another part of my HTML

Comment: I am not sure about the .item.active:last-child, unless you are tring to target the last child of .active. As far as I can tell there is only one active

Comment: @Huangism Although I understand what you mean, look at the demo it works.

Comment: Yeah it looks like this may also be giving me that flexibility I seek, let me play with this.. thanks