# Automatically scroll through tabs using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tab list code posted below.

```
                              //TabList
                              <ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
                                <li role="presentation" class="active">
                                    <a id="t1"  href="#tab1" aria-controls="tab1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="presentation">
                                    <a id="t2" href="#tab2" aria-controls="tab2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="presentation">
                                    <a id="t3" href="#tab3" aria-controls="tab3" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
                                </li>
                                <li role="presentation">
                                    <a id="t4" href="#tab4" aria-controls="tab4" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"></a>
                                </li>

                            </ul>
```

Each tab has a pic and some info. I want to automatically scroll through each tab every 5 seconds and then start at the first when the end is reached.

Using a setInterval function (Posted Below) i can get it to work but the infomation does not change. That is because it doesn't add an active class to the hyperlink.

```
//setInterval Function

     setInterval(function () {     
        //get currently-on tab
        var onTab = tabs.filter('.active');            
        //click either next tab, if exists, else first one
        var nextTab = onTab.index() < tabs.length - 1 ? onTab.next() : tabs.first();
        nextTab.click();
    }, 1000); 

  var tabs = $('#tabs li');

   //on click to tab, turn it on, and turn previously-on tab off
    tabs.click(function () {      
        $(this).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');                    

        }


    });
```

To get it working with the information showing when tab changes i use this code.

```
tabs.click(function () {   

            var curr = $('li.active');
            curr.removeClass('active');     
            curr.next().find("a").click();
            curr.next().addClass('active');

    });
```

The Problem is when it reaches the end of the it does not go back to the start i have looked at answers on stack-overflow like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153983/if-next-element-is-the-last-element) but can't get it to work. I feel like i cant see the forest for the trees and that it is a simple answer. Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var nextTab = onTab.index() < tabs.length - 1 ? onTab.next() : tabs.first();
```

hi yo:) Here when u get last element, u should add 'active' class to your first element of list:) Smth like:

```
var nextTab = onTab.index() < tabs.length - 1 ? onTab.next() : tabs.first().addClass('active');
```